# Как реализовать в приложении сначала загрузку данных с сервера, а затем обращение к базе данных?

Tags: android

У меня приложение сначала обращается к серверу, берет оттуда данные. А затем нужно сравнить эти данные с данными из БД. Но происходит так, что приложение начинает сравнивать данные до того, как они пришли с сервера, и выходит ошибка NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference. Как сделать так, чтобы все было по порядку(сначала запрос на сервер, а затем обращение к БД)?

Comment: Запрос к серверу идет не в основном потоке, а обращение к бд скорее всего в основном. По этому запрос отправлен, а выполнение кода продолжается, отсюда и ошибка. Подключите к запросу слушатель, из которого и делайте обращение к бд.

Comment: Нужен код чтобы понять причину

Comment: Сначала выполнять запрос, а уже по его выполнению - делать проверку. Если проблема не в этом, то нужен код для ее выявления.